# How can I store multiple strings into a list from regex?

Tags: python, arrays, list

This is my string:

```
<span class="word">blue</span><span class="word">red</span><span class="word">yellow</span><span class="word">orange</span>
```

Usually I would use this just to get one result into a variable:

```
result = re.search('(<span class="word">)(.*)(</span>)', string)
color = result.group(2)
```

But now I want to get **every** result from my string and store each into a list. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You should use BeautifulSoup for such purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall). For larger strings I recommend `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 0):

use findall instead of search

> findall() Find all substrings where the RE matches, and returns them as a list.
>
> finditer()    Find all substrings where the RE matches, and returns them as an iterator.

http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html